# Cohomology of a sheaf of functions locally constant along a foliation

Tags: sheaf-theory, foliations, cohomology, at.algebraic-topology

Take a smooth manifold $M^n$ with a smooth foliation $F$. Consider the sheaf $\cal F$ of $C^{\infty}$ functions on $M^n$, locally constant along the foliation $F$. What is known about Chech cohomology of such a sheaf?

I am pretty sure that such  a question was studied (and maybe even has a complete answer), but I don't know a reference.

A more specific question is: what happen when $F$ is 1-dimensional, given by integral trajectories of a  non-vanishing vector field? Or even more specifically, suppose $H^1(M^n)=0$ and we consider a Killing vector field $v$ on $M^n$ (i.e. $v$ is preserving a metric). Is it true the the sheaf of functions  $\cal F$ locally constant along trajectories of $v$ is acyclic? (we need $H^1(M^n)=0$, otherwise $S^1$ will be an obvious counterexample).

**An example of a foliation.** Consider the unit sphere $S^3$ in $\mathbb C^2$ and conisder the action of $\mathbb R$ via diagonal matrixes : $(z,w)\to (e^{ita}z, e^{itb}w)$ with $\frac{a}{b}$ irrational.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the semicontinuity theorem for cohomology along fibers?  Just curious.

Comment: Is such a sheaf pulled back from the quotient space $M/F$?

Comment: Chris, notice, that the clouse of a leaf ot F can easily have dimension larger then the dimesnion of the leaf. So the quotient can be non Hasudorf.... Akhil, I don't know how to answer your question... 

Comment: Chris -- there isn't a reasonable quotient space in general.

Comment: I realize that the quotient can be horrific, but you can still ask the question. Locally constant sheaves still make sense on bad spaces (locally the sheafification of the constant presheaves). I'm wondering if the cohomology group on M is just the usual sheaf cohomology of the bad quotient space. 

Comment: Dmitri, is there an example of an interesting non-trivial sheaf on $S^3$ which is locally constant along the fibers of the foliation (in your example)? Are there any that fail to come from the (bad) quotient space?

Comment: Chris - I think the answer is yes, for formal reasons: passing to sheaves takes colimits of spaces to limits, which in this case will mean sheaves on the quotient are the same as sheaves on M equivariant for our equivalence relation (which the given F is). Likewise its sheaf cohomology will be calculated by (derived functor of) invariant sections upstairs. (Unless I'm confused, which is likely, we're using something much weaker than descent here, just (co)continuity of spaces --> sheaves: I wouldn't know what kind of descent theorems held in this kind of setting..)

Comment: Chris, for you first question: In the case M^n=S^1, the sheaf F that we get is just the sheaf of locally constant functions on S^1, and its cohomology are surelly not the same as cohomology of the functions of the quotinet, which is a point.  For your second question: Personnaly I am horrified by non-Hausdrof spaces, so I would not be able to answer your question. But it is quite possible that you are right, that every locally constant sheaf on M^n comes from "the quotinet", it sounds plausible...  

Comment: Right. After playing a bit more, I think that the following is plausible: If the leaves are simply connected (so that on each leaf locally constant sheaf = constant sheaf), then the sheaf is pulled back from some sheaf on the (bad) quotient space. This should be true in Dmitri's $S^3$ example above. I think that the Cech cohomlogy on M will then be the same as the sheaf cohomology on the quotient (Since the quotient can be bad, and this can be *any* sheaf, this could be really realy exotic). 

Comment: (cont). In the case that the leaves are not simply connected (eg. $M = S^1$ with a single leaf), then it is more complicated. I think that you get something like a local system on the quotient and then $\mathcal{F}$ is a module or something like that for this local system. I'm not sure. 

Comment: I don't think it matters if the leaves are simply connected, as long as the sheaf is equivariant for the equivalence relation (ie is the constant sheaf along the fibers). In general (if F is just locally constant) I agree you'll get a sheaf (not a local system I don't think since the topology of leaves  jumps) which is the (group algebra) of relative $\pi_1$ and you'll get a module over this, but at this point I'm not sure working downstairs gains you anything (ie you're basically saying, a sheaf on the fibers of a fibration - ie pushing forward the stack of sheaves rather than descending)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nikita Markarian just explained to me (if there is a mistake below, it is mine), that the last and more specific question about acyclicity has 100% negative answer. Namely, we can consider the case $M^3=S^3$ ($H^1(S^3)=0$) and the foliation is given by the fibers of the Hopf fibration $S^3\to S^2$. In this chase the sheaf of functions locally constant on the fibers has a two-term resolution (by soft sheaves). The first term is given by all functions on $S^3$ and the second by $1$-forms on $S^3$, restricted to fibers. The differential is just the differential along the fibers. In this case it is clear, that the first cohomology is huge, it is parameterised by all functions on the base $S^2$.

So this condition $H^1(M^n)=0$ does not help at all.

It is a good exercise to apply the same reasoning to the other foliation on $S^3$, described in the question.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but your question rang a particular bell: namely the paper [*On the relative de Rham sequence*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2043718) by Buchdahl, which I read when I was a graduate student and I used in my own research.  My motivation at the time was to understand so-called *classical BRST cohomology*, which is a homological approach to symplectic reduction.  This procedure is a subquotient, whose last step is a quotient of the "constraint surface" by a foliation defined by the integral submanifolds of the hamiltonian vector fields corresponding to "first-class constraints".  (The classical case is when the constraints are the components of an equivariant momentum mapping, but the general case of first-class constraints only yields a foliation which might not fiber.)  One is interested therefore in functions which are locally constant on the leaves of the foliation.  This can be identified with the zeroth Cech cohomology of the complex of "vertical forms" which is a special case of the relative de Rham complex of Buchdahl's.

Comment: Jose, thanks a lot! I will have a look on this article once at work

Answer (score 2):

I am joining this discussion a bit late, but let me add an example. If you consider a smooth minimal action of Z on the circle S^1 the suspension gives a flow on the torus. If the action is C^2 conjugate to an irrational rotation, then the transverse basic cohomology is finite dimensional. But if the action is only topologically conjugate to a rotation, then the basic cohomology may be infinite. The literature on this is quite a long time ago, in the 1970's perhaps. here is one reference

Haefliger, A.and Banghe, Li
Currents on a circle invariant by a Fuchsian group. Geometric dynamics (Rio de Janeiro, 1981), 369–378, Lecture Notes in Math., 1007, Springer, Berlin, 1983.

Here is a more recent article

Avila, Artur and Kocsard, Alejandro
Cohomological equations and invariant distributions for minimal circle diffeomorphisms. Duke Math. J. 158 (2011), no. 3, 501–536.

and there is one more artcile that is likely relevant to the question

Lott, John
Invariant currents on limit sets. Comment. Math. Helv. 75 (2000), no. 2, 319–350.

Answer (score 0):

I am also very interested in "What is known about Chech cohomology of such a sheaf?", so if you got more information I would be interested.

A fine and torsionless resolution is given by foliated ("tangential" sometimes is used to refer to it) cohomology.

Transversal structures gives a great deal of information as well.

More related to what Chris said about $M/\mathcal{F}$ is Basic cohomology of foliated manifolds. Basic cohomology can be infinite dimensional, so it can or can not satisfy a Poincarè duality. It seems to be well cover in the literature the riemannian foliation case.

Comment: It appears that the relation between basic cohomology (base-like cohomology as it was coined by Reinhart) and $M/\mathcal{F}$ is contained in this paper arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0903/0903.2871v1.pdf
